# BLOB to String conversion - DB2

Tags: db2, blob, sqoop

A table in DB2 contains BLOB data. I need to convert it into String so that it can be viewed in a readable format. I tried options like

1. getting blob object and converting to byte array
2. string buffer reader
3. sqoop import using --map-column-java and --map-column-hive options.

After these conversions also i am not able to view the data in readable format. Its in an unreadable format like 1f8b0000..

Please suggest a solution on how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Are you certain that the column contains text?  Do you know the encoding of the column? Is it EBCDIC?   Edit your question to add Db2-version and Db2-platform (Z/OS, i-Series, LUW), and column encoding information.

Comment: if it's text, why is it in a BLOB (binary large object) instead of a CLOB (character large object)?

Comment: I haven't seen the data. we are trying to get the data from the db. Only thing i know about the data is, it is in gzip compressed format and its an xml data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to look at the CAST function.

```css
SELECT CAST(BLOB_VAR as VARCHAR(SIZE) CCSID UNICODE) as CHAR_FLD
```

Also, be advised that max value of SIZE is 32K.

Let me know if you tried this.

Comment: I tried with the given code, still getting data in unreadable format.

Comment: I am assuming that you are working on Java. Try adding CCSID to CAST. 

Try this one:

'SELECT CAST(BLOB_VAR as VARCHAR(SIZE) CCSID UNICODE) as CHAR_FLD'

Answer (score 0):

1f8b0000 indicates the data in gzip form and therefore you have to unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

First, fire this query:

```
Select `cast(blob_field_name as varchar) blob_field_name from table`
```

Later, use the output of the above query to execute this query:

```
Select x'output' from table
```

Here, the output generated from the first query will be a sequence of numbers separated by space.

This output should then be placed between the quotes in the second query.
This will output the blob data.